# Create latest news section on website

Tags: web, feed

I'm trying to create a latest news section to the front page of my website. What is the simplest way to go about this? I know I could use WordPress but I don't necessarily want it to be a blog, just a scrolling news section.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about http://jackjohnsonmusic.com/archive/news

I've searched for ages on the internet and found nothing about this, if anyone has any links that maybe useful I'd appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what your looking for but I have used it in the past. It takes news feeds from RSS and puts them on your site.
    http://feed.mikle.com

Comment: It's not quite what I'm looking for, I need to add my own news updates. I know I can do this by going into the html but I guess what I'm wondering is how do you think the site I linked in the question goes about this, like how is it updated?